# How to change the keras module version?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras

I got the same error found here in this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293844/pythontypeerror-variable-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-constraint?answertab=active#tab-top

and in the answers I found the solution which is "change the keras module version", but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: try this :  pip install keras=="version name"  , version name that you want to change

Comment: thank you @JignashaRoyala 
now the problem will be "which version!",i'll check this out
(btw i have the latest version, is that can cause such a problem?)

Comment: The easy solution is using Anaconda (a python installation that automatically manages versions so things are probably compatible). The hard solution is to find out what your tensorflow version is and search the internet for the keras version that was built on top of your tensorflow version. (Assuming the error is between keras and tensorflow here, but that may not be true).

Comment: @DanielMöller i'm using anaconda3, tensorflow 1.8.0, and keras 2.1.6!

Comment: My anaconda for some reason decided that the best tensorflow version for it was 1.5.0 for keras 2.1.5. (Very very recently, so I think this is the best compatibility for now).

Comment: Did you install tensorflow from `pip`? I installed it from `conda`.

Comment: to be honest, I don't remember, but I think that I used pip

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided in question section is not accessible anymore.

However, (as mentioned by @Jignasha Royala), you can install specific `keras` by putting it's version detail as below:

```
pip install keras==2.1.6   # (pip install keras=="version name")
```

For `TensorFlow 1.8.0`, compatible `keras` versions are `2.1.5 or 2.1.6`.

Please check this [list](https://www.codestudyblog.com/cs2201py/40101172152.html) of `TensorFlow` compatible `keras` versions along with the `python` version. Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220990/compatible-keras-and-tensorflow-version#:%7E:text=For%20me%2C%20keras%202.1.,3.6%20worked%20for%20Tensorflow%201.8.) similar issue for your reference.

**Note:** This is suggested to upgrade `TensorFlow` to the [latest version](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for utilizing the best available features. `TensorFlow 2.8` is available with inbuilt `keras 2.8` and several other built-in features.