# compatible Keras and Tensorflow version

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a separated training and inference system. The inference system has tensorflow version 1.8 (yes, I know, it is old, but I have no say on upgrading the system...).

I am building my model in Keras, then try to convert it to pb model for inferencing. I have trouble finding the compatible Keras version could work with tensorflow 1.8. I am wondering what's the Keras version for tensorflow 1.8 ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One of my environment has `tensorflow==1.8.0` I have checked with `print(keras.__version__)` and it returns 2.1.5-tf my whole code was :

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

> 2.1.5-tf

Answer (score 0):

For me, keras 2.1.6 with Python 3.6 worked for Tensorflow 1.8. Here is the [link](https://mckayward.github.io/floyd-docs/guides/environments/) where I found the version of Keras from.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and probably should use the Keras that is in your tensorflow version.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
```

Comment: @Edamame can you accept my answer as this is "by the book" approach?